# Most efficient way to run tests against this stored data

Tags: java

Sorry for the not too informative title, I couldn't think of anything better. When I say efficient I mean code that isn't cpu intensive.

**Problem:**
Imagine a 3D spaceship made out of blocks, like one build in minecraft. I want to store the location of every single block in this shapeship in a self-made Ship class.

For this I was using `private List<ShipBlock> shipBlocks;` inside the Ship class. ShipBlock here is a self-made class, which holds a position in the form of a vector `Vec3(int x, int y, int z)` as well as some other information irrelevant to this question.

But now I want to perform a test on the ship. Wether the ship contains a ShipBlock on a certain testPosition (x, y, z), and if so return the ShipBlock for this. I have however not found a way to do this efficiently. Looping through the entire List and to test every position against the testposition is pretty expensive and I'd like for it to be fast.

So instead, I decided to make a `Map<Vec3, ShipBlock> shipBlocksMap` to store the information. Where the key would be the ShipBlock's position. I could simply do `shipBlocksMap.get(testPosition)` and it would return the correct ShipBlock if the ship has a ShipBlock in that position. If not it would return null.

It seemed to be exactly what I wanted, untill I moved the ship and all ShipBlock's got new positions. I learned here that key's in a map don't change if the object you gave as a key changes. And thus if I now were to use `shipBlocksMap.get(testPosition)` using a position that is in the moved ship, it would return null as the key's are still the old positions. (Sorry if it's confusing, I'm not sure how to explain it better)

**Question:**
The question that I'm asking here is: Say if the ship can contain tens of thousands of ShipBlocks, what is the most efficient way to test if it contains a ShipBlock with a certain position. And in what way should I store the ship's ShipBlocks so this check goes efficiently?

**Code:**
Incase anyone wants to see it here is the code to the Ship and the ShipBlock classes.

```
public class ShipBlock 
{
    public Vec3 position;
    public String shipBlockType;

    public ShipBlock(Vec3 position, String shipBlockType)
    {
        this.position= position;
        this.shipBlockType = shipBlockType;
    }
}

public class Ship 
{
    private Map<Vec3, ShipBlock> shipBlocksMap;

    public Ship(Map<Vec3, ShipBlock> shipBlocksMap)
    {
        this.shipBlocksMap = shipBlocksMap;
    }

    public ShipBlock containsShipBlock(Vec3 position)
    {
        return shipBlocksMap.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you, at the time when the block is moved, remove it from the map and re-insert it at the new position?

Comment: maybe you can give ship a location, then store all the blocks of the ship relative to the ship's location, thus, if ship moves you only need to modify the ship's location and not all the ship blocks.

Comment: @Diego Martinoia Wouldn't that be, if the ship contains lots of blocks, be pretty inefficient? Using .remove() and .put() for every single block everytime the ship is moved.

Comment: Yes if you store every block. But if the blocks move all together, as other have pointed out, you can just store their reference point (the ship)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most important design change is to save the blocks' positions *relative* to the ship's position.

This way, you do not need to change the keys of the blocks when the ship moves, and can easily use your `Map<Vec3, ShipBlock> shipBlocksMap` for a constant-time test, where the keys are then the relative positions.
You can get the relative position by computing (conceptually) `relative_block_pos = absolute_block_pos - ship_pos`.

That means you need to store *the* position of the ship.
As one option, you may to simply choose the first block of a ship as the ship's position, thus the first block always has coordinates `(0, 0, 0)`.

This way, changing the coordinates of all blocks is reduced to a minimum (but should be not required in most cases).

Comment: If the points do not move rigidly with the ship, you can also have another map that, for those points that are in moving parts of the ship, store their relative position

Comment: That sounds like a better way to store this yeah, but that still leaves the problem of how do I test wether a block is part of the ship? I'd get the relative position by subtracting the ship position from the testPosition, but then I'd still need to somehow test all of the shipBlocks against the relative position.

Comment: I clarified my answer a bit. You can simply use your `Map<Vec3, ShipBlock> shipBlocksMap` as you posted in your question.

Comment: Oh after you edited I understood, since the relative positions are the keys used in the map. In that case question answered I believe, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A space-partitioning tree may be your best option; see [space-partitioning trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Space-partitioning_trees). Half of your model universe might be empty, and in many of these structures, a single test would reveal this, and could contribute to future tests until that half of the universe changes in some way. The onus is on you to maintain the structure, but it sounds like changes to the structure are outnumbered by tests. Another approach might be to surround blocks or clusters of blocks with meta-balls or Voronoi hulls so that you can reduce each volume of tests into a single test.